# Redux returns "middleware is not a function"

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm receiving the TypeError: middleware is not a function. There some similar questions with answers which doesn't seem to apply in my case. I'm planning to make an axios/async request. Here is my implementation of my index.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import  { Provider }  from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import axios from 'axios';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import logger from 'redux-logger';

const PATH_BASE = 'https://itunes.apple.com/search';
const PATH_TERM = 'term=';
const COUNTRY = 'country=es';
const ALBUMS = 'entity=album';
const LIMIT = 'limit=60';

const booleanReducer = (state = { grid:true, additionalPages:false }, action) => {
  if (action.type === 'GRID'){
    return state = {
      ...state,
      grid:!state.grid
    }
  }
  if (action.type === 'ADDITIONALPAGES'){
    return state = {
      ...state,
      additionalPages:!state.additionalPages
    }
  }
  return state;
};

const searchItunesReducer = (state = { searchTerm:'', itunes:null }, action) => {
  if (action.type === 'SEARCHTERM'){
    return state = {
      ...state,
      searchTerm:action.payload
      }
    }
  if (action.type === 'FETCHITUNESALBUMS'){
    return state = {
      ...state,

      }
    }
      return state;
  }

const middleware = applyMiddleware(thunk, logger());
const store = createStore(combineReducers({booleanReducer,searchItunesReducer}),middleware);
console.log(store.getState());

store.subscribe(() =>{
  console.log("store updated!", store.getState());
});

registerServiceWorker();
ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={store}>
  <App />
  </Provider>

, document.getElementById('root'));
```

If i remove the line `const middleware = applyMiddleware(thunk, logger());` and the `const middleware` from the `const store` the app loads with not an issue. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You're calling `logger` and using its result as middleware; shouldn't it just be `applyMiddleware(thunk, logger)`?

Comment: You're right...thanks

Answer (score 0):

Was having kind of the same issue with this code from a React/ Redux tutorial:

NOT WORKING FOR ME:

```
    import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from "redux";
    import thunk from "redux-thunk";
    import promise from "redux-promise-middleware";
    import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
    import rootReducer from "./reducers";
    const middleware = composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(promise(), thunk));
    export default createStore(rootReducer, middleware);
```

My solution:
Because the createStore() function was asking for a function, I created one. Would not accept an arrow function for some reason (or I didn't do it properly). Also I rmnoved the promise() function call and only stated promise a parameter. This got me going through compile.

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import  promise from "redux-promise-middleware";
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import rootReducer from "./reducers";

function middleware() {
    return composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(promise, thunk));
}

export default createStore(rootReducer, middleware());
```